# Reading data from standard input using two threads

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, pipe, cat

I am trying to read data from standard input (stdin) using two threads but I'm not able to read data properly. I tried on Linux platform using gcc compiler. I am trying to read data using cat command and pipe.

```
cat Test.txt | ./a.out
```

I got output like this:

[image: img]

What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// Declaring mutex
pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void *input(void *ptr)
{

    while(1)
    {
        char str[20];
        memset(str, '\0', 20);
        int result;
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        result = read(STDIN_FILENO, str, sizeof str);
        if (result <= 0) 
        {
            printf("====\n");
            pthread_exit(NULL);
            return NULL;
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        printf("Reader: %s\n", str);
    }
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t t1, t2;

    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, input, NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, input, NULL);

    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t2, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

My **Test.txt** file data:

```
AAAAAAABBBCCCDDDDDDEFG
mmmmmmmmmmgggggggggwwwghgmaaaaabbb
rrrrrrrssghgmtttttddddrrr
a
```

Comment: `%s` expects a NUL-terminated string

Comment: Please show textual output as text, not as a screenshot of your entire desktop.

Answer (score 1):

The `%s` `printf` format specifier requires a null-terminated string. You are passing it a string which is not null-terminated. This causes undefined behavior.

I suggest you change the line

`result = read(STDIN_FILENO, str, sizeof str);`

to:

`result = read(STDIN_FILENO, str, sizeof str - 1);`

Also, you should unlock the mutex **before** calling `pthread_exit`, otherwise you risk a deadlock.

Instead of using `memset` on the entire array, it would be more efficient to add the line

`str[result] = '\0';`

immediately before the `printf` statement.